# velocity not being initiated when triggered by Quartz Job

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, velocity

Velocity Engine is being used in my project for sending mails on user action and on job trigger.

While the mails that are sent on user action are perfectly fine, The mails being sent by jobs are sometimes received with empty content. This is very random and i cannot seem to connect it with any cause. There are no Error logs when this happens. (I did get a Velocity could not be initialized error once, before adding the NullLogChute property. I was advised that this would solve the exception, but all it did was to stop the exception from coming up in the logs. mails still have empty content) Please help!

Earlier exception:

```
ERROR 2012-07-29 05:00:00,219 com.myProject.util.VelocityUtil - Velocity could not be initialized!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Velocity could not be initialized!
..
..
Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute with the current runtime configuration.
```

I am setting the velocity config properties in my spring servlet xml :

```
<bean id="velocityUtil" class="com.myProject.util.VelocityUtil" >
 <property name="velocityConfiguration">
  <props> 
   <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
   <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</prop>
   <prop key="runtime.log.logsystem.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogChute</prop> 
  </props>
 </property>
```

Quartz properties set in spring servlet:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey"><value>applicationContext</value></property>
     <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">Quartz</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export">false</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy">false</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">1</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">EES.QRTZ_</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
    <list>
        <ref bean="Mod1CronTrigger" />
        <ref bean="Mod2CronTrigger" />
        <ref bean="Mod3CronTrigger" />
        <ref bean="Mod4CronTrigger" /> 
        <ref bean="Mod5CronTrigger" /> 
        <ref bean="Mod6CronTrigger" />
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Each of the triggers in the `<list>` define the jobDetail and CronExpression. for example,

```
<bean id="Mod1CronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="Mod1Job"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 3 1/1 * ? *"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean name="Mod1Job" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.myProject.jobs.Mod1Job" />
    <property name="name" value="Mod1Job" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Did you try putting a logger in your Quartz job which prints all  the required Debug information? e.g. The Velocity Context, all the values which are sent to velocity etc.?